# Is there an API function to display "Fraction Cached" for an RDD?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

On the *Storage* tab of the PySparkShell application UI ([server]:8088) I can see information about an RDD I am using. One of the column is *Fraction Cached*.

How can I retrieve this percentage programatically?

I can use `getStorageLevel()` to get some information about RDD caching but not *Fraction Cached*.

Do I have to calculate it myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SparkContext.getRDDStorageInfo` is probably the thing you're looking for. It returns an `Array` of [`RDDInfo`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.storage.RDDInfo) which provides information about:

- Memory size.
- Total number of partitions.
- Number of cached partitions.

It is not directly exposed in PySpark so you'll have to be a bit creative:

```
from operator import truediv

storage_info =  sc._jsc.sc().getRDDStorageInfo()

[{
    "memSize": s.memSize(), 
    "numPartitions": s.numPartitions(), 
    "numCachedPartitions": s.numCachedPartitions(),
    "fractionCached": truediv(s.numCachedPartitions(), s.numPartitions())
} for s in storage_info]
```

If you have access to the [REST API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api) you can of course use it directly:

```
import requests

url = "http://{0}:{1}/api/v1/applications/{2}/storage/rdd/".format(
    host, port, sc.applicationId
)

[r.json() for r  in [
   requests.get("{0}{1}".format(url, rdd.get("id"))) for
   rdd  in requests.get(url).json()
] if r.status_code == 200]
```