# How to check the list of cache data frames/rdds/tables in Spark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am planning to save some data frames/tables to cache in Spark. I would like to know how many dataframes/tables are cached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can see details of cached RDDs/Dataframes via the Spark UI's storage tab or via the [REST API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api).  [image]

Answer (score 4):

You can call the underlying java object in pySpark

```
[{
    "name": s.name(),     
    "memSize_MB": float(s.memSize())/ 2**20 , 
    "memSize_GB": float(s.memSize())/ 2**30, 
    "diskSize_MB": float(s.diskSize())/ 2**20, 
    "diskSize_GB": float(s.diskSize())/ 2**30, 
    "numPartitions": s.numPartitions(), 
    "numCachedPartitions": s.numCachedPartitions(),
    "callSite": s.callSite(),
    "externalBlockStoreSize": s.externalBlockStoreSize(),
    "id": s.id(),
    "isCached": s.isCached(),
    "parentIds": s.parentIds(),
    "scope": s.scope(),
    "storageLevel": s.storageLevel(),
    "toString": s.toString()
} for s in sc._jsc.sc().getRDDStorageInfo()]
```

See [Spark Java Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/storage/RDDInfo.html) for more info.

modified from [zero323](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1560062/zero323)'s answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42003733/5060792

Answer (score 1):

You can follow what Brian said. As per Pyspark, it doesn't have the '`sc.getPersistentRDDs`' method like the Scala API.

You can track the issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2141)